# PLsql or Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Looking for a help on populating the data from  table1 to  table2. 
I have table1 of below columns and data sample as below. 
When days is 5 it needs to populate data on other table2 with 8 hours based on days (sat and sun needs to be 0 )

Table 1:

```
id  year    month      days
101 2017    September   5
102 2017    September   4
103 2017    September   3
104 2017    September   2
```

Table 2 which needs to be populated as below:

```
Id   Month      1   2(Sat)  3(Sunday)   4   5
101 September   8   0       0   8   8   8   8
102 September   8   0       0   8   8   8   0
103 September   8   0       0   8   8   0   0
104 September   8   0      0    8   0   0   0
```

Comment: it is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the desired result with:

```
select 
  id,
  month,
  case when days >= 1 then 8 end as friday,
  0                              as saturday,
  0                              as sunday,
  case when days >= 2 then 8 end as monday,
  case when days >= 3 then 8 end as tuesday,
  case when days >= 4 then 8 end as wednesday,
  case when days >= 5 then 8 end as thursday
from table1
where year = 2017;
```

In order to fill table2 with this data, you can use an insert select:

```
insert into table2 (id, month, saturday, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday)
select 
  id,
  ...
from table1
where year = 2017;
```